# Can I use the macOS Terminal as a terminal emulator for a specific device?

Tags: terminal

I'm using xhyve to run Linux virtual machines on my computer. One commit [implements autopty support](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve/pull/87/commits/a85426bced00107e3cd7628c86e0d83840d3f396):

> When running xhyve with autopty, before booting the guest OS, it
>   outputs the slave pty device path users can plug into using screen,
>   minicom or the terminal emulator or their preference.
>   Ex:
>
> ```
> screen /dev/ttys003
> ```

What if I want to use the macOS Terminal application? Can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried as in the example given?

Comment: That launches `screen`, a terminal emulator running in the macOS terminal emulator. It doesn't start a Terminal window directly connected to the TTY. `screen` doesn't resize nicely, it intercepts things like mouse scrolls instead of passing through to the host window, etc.

Comment: Terminal needs a shell of some sort to work with. One could probably simulate this with a sophisticated invocation of `nc` or `cu` but I'm not sure it's worth the hassle. Mouse and resizing issues are probably rather a matter of configuration (it seems to work if I run `screen` locally for instance).